# Why do we care about removing correlated predictors in predictive modeling?

Tags: predictive-models, interpretation, predictor

Many basic methods in predictive modeling/statistical learning are good at picking one of the correlated predictors while removing others, such as Lasso. However, isn't it the case that in general, the more predictors, the better the prediction? If so, why do we care about removing correlated predictors when making prediction?

Reasons that I can think of include

(1) Models are more parsimonious and easier to interpret, if interpretation of the relationship between the predictor and outcome is important;

(2) some of the correlated terms, if not eliminated, may be associated with other variables that can confound the relationship between the main predictor and the outcome, making the prediction worse.

I scratch my head but still could not come up with a good reason...so if you have a better explanation I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: so for L1/L2 regularised  GLMs, Neural Nets, SVMs you are right. I am not so sure about tree based models

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think this advice comes mostly from linear models where correlated predictors can lead to inflated standard error and model instability.  There are better methods of dealing with these problems than choosing which predictors to keep and you've listed some of them.